# Play Framework Greenscript, NullPointerException

Tags: java, playframework, greenscript

playframework 1.2.3 , greenscript 1.2.6k

When accessing a page I get a NullPointerException on line 174 of GreenScriptPlugin.java

Line 174 is the last line in the example below (JobsPlugin.executor ...) :

```
    @Override
    public void afterApplicationStart() {
        Properties p = Play.configuration;
        for (ResourceType type: ResourceType.values()) {
            final Minimizer m = type == ResourceType.JS ? jsM_ : cssM_;
            String s = fetchProp_(p, String.format("greenscript%s.cache.check", type.getExtension()));
            int i = "never".equalsIgnoreCase(s) ? -1 : Time.parseDuration(s); 
            if (-1 != i) {
                Job<Object> j = new Job<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void doJob() {
                        m.checkCache();
                    }
                };
                JobsPlugin.executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(j, i, i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We had trouble integrating greenscript as well. Now we use the [Press plugin](http://www.playframework.org/modules/press-1.0.23/home), which works like a charm. It's pretty easy to integrate and test, perhaps you should give it a shot.

Comment: Hi evandongen, may I know what's the trouble you've encountered integrating greenscript? Please don't put me wrong, as the author of greenscript I just want to make this tool become better. thx... Green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found that google app engine which was having its own errors was causing this.  After this was fixed greenscript worked as expected